# Dynamic nested loop - recursion

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I would like to generate a list of numbers who's digits are in ascending order.

```
for x in range(1,10):
    for y in range(x,10):
        for z in range(y,10):
            print(x,y,z)
```

Is it possible for me to convert this probably to a recursion such that I can vary the nesting depth ?

Notes:

In my application I have something other than printing and I'd like to keep minimum burden on the print statement.

I am aware of the `itertools.product` and **it's not suitable** for my purpose as I have to remove the unnecessary combinations later.

Due to the same reason generating all `n` digit numbers and removing the unnecessary ones won't work as well

Thanks

Comment: you want a list of numbers?

Comment: not really, right now I have a list of tuples generated with below list comprehension but any formatting would do. I am basically looking for the algo.

Comment: test = [(x,y,z) for x in range(1,10) for y in range(x,10) for z in range(y,10) if sum((x,y,z))==10]

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What makes you think recursion is better? Describe the problem, as the end goal not as one solution

Comment: Of possible relevance [Recursive Function to Replace Nested For Loops](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577415-recursive-function-to-replace-nested-for-loops-car/)

Comment: So what is wrong with the list comprehension in your comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement()`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 10), 2))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9), (8, 8), (8, 9), (9, 9)]

>>> list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 10), 3))
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 4), (1, 1, 5), (1, 1, 6), (1, 1, 7), (1, 1, 8), (1, 1, 9), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 6), (1, 2, 7), (1, 2, 8), (1, 2, 9), (1, 3, 3), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 3, 7), (1, 3, 8), (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 4), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 4, 9), (1, 5, 5), (1, 5, 6), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (1, 5, 9), (1, 6, 6), (1, 6, 7), (1, 6, 8), (1, 6, 9), (1, 7, 7), (1, 7, 8), (1, 7, 9), (1, 8, 8), (1, 8, 9), (1, 9, 9), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 4), (2, 2, 5), (2, 2, 6), (2, 2, 7), (2, 2, 8), (2, 2, 9), (2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 3, 7), (2, 3, 8), (2, 3, 9), (2, 4, 4), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 4, 9), (2, 5, 5), (2, 5, 6), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8), (2, 5, 9), (2, 6, 6), (2, 6, 7), (2, 6, 8), (2, 6, 9), (2, 7, 7), (2, 7, 8), (2, 7, 9), (2, 8, 8), (2, 8, 9), (2, 9, 9), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 4), (3, 3, 5), (3, 3, 6), (3, 3, 7), (3, 3, 8), (3, 3, 9), (3, 4, 4), (3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 6), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (3, 4, 9), (3, 5, 5), (3, 5, 6), (3, 5, 7), (3, 5, 8), (3, 5, 9), (3, 6, 6), (3, 6, 7), (3, 6, 8), (3, 6, 9), (3, 7, 7), (3, 7, 8), (3, 7, 9), (3, 8, 8), (3, 8, 9), (3, 9, 9), (4, 4, 4), (4, 4, 5), (4, 4, 6), (4, 4, 7), (4, 4, 8), (4, 4, 9), (4, 5, 5), (4, 5, 6), (4, 5, 7), (4, 5, 8), (4, 5, 9), (4, 6, 6), (4, 6, 7), (4, 6, 8), (4, 6, 9), (4, 7, 7), (4, 7, 8), (4, 7, 9), (4, 8, 8), (4, 8, 9), (4, 9, 9), (5, 5, 5), (5, 5, 6), (5, 5, 7), (5, 5, 8), (5, 5, 9), (5, 6, 6), (5, 6, 7), (5, 6, 8), (5, 6, 9), (5, 7, 7), (5, 7, 8), (5, 7, 9), (5, 8, 8), (5, 8, 9), (5, 9, 9), (6, 6, 6), (6, 6, 7), (6, 6, 8), (6, 6, 9), (6, 7, 7), (6, 7, 8), (6, 7, 9), (6, 8, 8), (6, 8, 9), (6, 9, 9), (7, 7, 7), (7, 7, 8), (7, 7, 9), (7, 8, 8), (7, 8, 9), (7, 9, 9), (8, 8, 8), (8, 8, 9), (8, 9, 9), (9, 9, 9)]
```

Comment: This is a very good solution as well. I ended up using this. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Here, You have to pass the list of numbers as well as depth, so that you can constantly increse the list with each `recursion`.

```py
def get_nums(depth=0,pre_list=[[1]]):
    if depth==0:
        return pre_list
    new_list=[]
    for num in pre_list:
        n=num[-1]
        for i in range(n,10):
            new_list.append(num+[i])
    return get_nums(depth-1,new_list)

print(get_nums(3))
```

Comment: Thanks very much Ateryagaurav for having a look at this and your contribution.

Comment: so you wanted list of numbers not the numbers? you said format didn't matter, anyway i have edited this to output the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive solution,

```py
def rec(s,idx,num):
    if idx>=len(s)-1:
        print(s)
        return
    for i in range(num,10):
        s[idx+1] = i # change next number
        rec(s,idx+1,i) # recurse

s = [1,1,1]
idx = -1
num = s[0]
rec(s,idx,num)
```

---

Output

```
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 4]
[1, 1, 5]
[1, 1, 6]
[1, 1, 7]
[1, 1, 8]
[1, 1, 9]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 5]
[1, 2, 6]
[1, 2, 7]
[1, 2, 8]
[1, 2, 9]
[1, 3, 3]
...and so on until [9,9,9]
```